# JavaFx empty Combo Box

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, javafx-8

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> hariComboBox ;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> bulanComboBox;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton baratRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton indonesiaRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private TextField nameDisplayTextField;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        this.bulanComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        this.bulanComboBox.getItems().addAll(
                "Januari",
                "Febuari",
                "Maret",
                "Mei",
                "Juni",
                "Juli",
                "Agustust",
                "September",
                "Oktober",
                "November",
                "Desember"
        );
    }    

}
```

this is my class but when i try my ui, the comboBox is empty and has nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.bulanComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
```

You replace the instance of the already initialized and injected `ComboBox` by the FXML loader. Drop this line.

Answer (score 1):

Create an ObservableList and set the items in the list to the ComboBox.

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> bulanComboBox 

public ObservableList<String> monthsList= FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Januari",
            "Febuari",
            "Maret",
            "Mei",
            "Juni",
            "Juli",
            "Agustust",
            "September",
            "Oktober",
            "November",
            "Desember"
    );

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
         bulanComboBox.setItems(monthsList);
}
```

I would think this is the most common/easiest way to set up a ComboBox